# How to connect eccomerce template to a database?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So basically I downloaded this website template from here https://w3layouts.com/super-market-e-commerce-online-shopping-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

Im looking to create my own eccomerce store. How would I go about attaching this website to a database so users can register/login and so i can update the catalogue and recieve orders? Any help would be appreciated..Leaning more towards any guides couldnt seem to find any.

Answer (score 2):

The template you downloaded is just the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for animations. There are a wide variety of routes you could take in connecting it to a database and adding the user account functionality.

I suggest reading the answers to this question: [E-commerce from scratch or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325094/e-commerce-from-scratch-or-not)

**If you are looking to have an e-commerce site for the purpose of selling items**, your best option is to not reinvent the wheel and use a service such as [OpenCart](https://www.opencart.com/).

However, **if you want a learning experience**, then look up guides on PHP and MySQL. PHP is a server-side scripting language that is used for processing information on the server, which is something you would be doing a lot in an e-commerce application. MySQL is a database application that will store your data. These two technologies, along with the template, will be enough to create a basic e-commerce site. You will also need a web host and a domain.

I suggested PHP and MySQL for their widespread usage and availability of tutorials and guides. There are many more server-side languages and database systems that could be used for this project.